# How to redirect invalid url to a valid url in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a valid url of the type http://example.com/valid/. Using nginx how do i redirect a url of type http://example.com/valid/dsdhshd to my valid url?

I tried:

```
location /valid/ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass http://example.com/valid/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But it gives a 500 internal server error.

I also tried location `return 301 $scheme://example.com/valid/;` but this just put me in an infinite redirection loop.

Comment: if you want to prevent the redirection loop, create a new location `location = /valid`

Comment: are those simple html files, or is there a backend that handles this ? (php, python, ruby)

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady they are simple html, css and js files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send the redirect to the client, don't proxy the request and simply send it.

```
server {
    # Your server configuration ...

    # Enclose regular expressions in default location.
    location / {

        location /valid {
            location ~ /valid/.+ {
                try_files $uri @invalid;
            }

            # Handle the request to the valid URL ...
        }

    }

    location @invalid {
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name/valid;
    }
}
```

That should do the trick. You did get a redirect loop because your location block also matched the `/valid/` URL itself, something you don't wanted to match. You only want to match URLs which have something after that string, e.g. `/valid/foo`. That is exactly what the regular expression in the location block above is ensuring.

Comment: but what if a url of the type http://example.com/valid/css/main.css comes along. In that case also it will get returned.

Comment: You need a pattern to identify which URLs are invalid and which are valid and create a regular expression which ensures exactly that for you.

Comment: i use this regex `~* \.(favicon\.ico|ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$` for that. can i use it here somehow?

Comment: any url starting with `/valid/` and ending with the above regex gets hosted else it gets redirected to `/valid/`. How do i write it though?

Comment: I extended the answer with handling of existing static files and redirecting any other requests.

Comment: would this work?  `location /valid/ {
  location ~* \.(favicon\.ico|ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
   #host as usual
  }

  location /valid/.+ {
   return 301 $scheme://$server_name/valid;
  }
 }`

Comment: The configuration I posted is faster, but yes, this would work as well (but really bad style).

Comment: what regex can i use for @invalid?

Comment: `@invalid` is a named location block which is used together with the `try_files` directive. The `try_files` directive checks if the requested URL is actually a static file which is present on the server and will simply deliver it if it is (no matter if this is ICO, PNG, or what not). If the requested URL does not point to a file it continues to the named location `@invalid` which yields the 301 return. DONE :)

Comment: in ur configuration where would the url `example.com/valid/` go? notice the last slash.

Comment: To `location /valid {` since there are no characters after the last slash and the request points to a directory. Nginx will look for the index document within the directory or proxy it if your location is configured to do so. You should definitely read the nginx documentation regarding these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

here's a sample i could think about

```
server {
  location /valid {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect_invalid;
  }
  location @redirect_invalid {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/valid;
  }
}
```

But this will be very specific and if there's many folders you'll need to add each separately, I can't think of a method to make this generic for all folders, maybe someone else could help me with this.

Comment: Regarding `$http_host`: Do not use user supplied variables in your configuration. They are slow (parsing) and insecure. Your configuration will not allow him to process the request to `/valid` since your `try_files` will directly go to the named location.

Comment: well that would be weird if my server name was something like `server_name localhost example.com;`

Comment: In this case use `$hostname` which is generated by nginx for you.

Comment: requests to `/valid` will match the `$uri/`, or `$uri` depending if it's a folder or file

Comment: Which requires an additional `location` block to be configured and bloats your configuration. ;)

Comment: I'll take a look on that `$hostname`

Comment: You should always smell something burning if you access any `$http_` variable, that's not only true for nginx, that's true for any software out there. It's user supplied, it's insecure, it needs proper validation.

Comment: The `-1` was for the sum of things. Your answer contains something risky, syntax errors, and does not meet the requirements of the question. It was nothing personal, I think and gauge before I simply up or down vote something. Of course you can improve and I might change my mind. ;)

Comment: my answer does solve the question and it has no syntax errors, I've tested it my self and it works just fine, you can check your self, http://test.abushady.com/valid/existing.html, http://test.abushady.com/valid/non-existing.html, and http://test.abushady.com/valid

Comment: Check the diff from my edit regarding syntax errors. It does not meet the requirements since processing of the original valid location is missing (yes you answered that to me in a comment).

Comment: The OP said that the files are just static files (I've asked that in the comments) so a simple `index index.html` would handle that, as i stated that's a sample not the whole answer, and regarding the diff those are typos, anyone could miss them

Comment: I'm not trying to argue for no reason, i just think those mistakes are not worth a vote down, at least for me people need to do more severe mistakes to deserve one, anyways thanks for the `$http_host` vs `$server_name` and `$hosename` tip

Comment: That's a discussion for [META](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451) and every user is allowed to decide when to vote on his or her behalf. Don’t forget that I loose some of my reputation by doing so (if it’s only about reputation here for you). Just edited your post again. I’d also like to add, that I didn’t read the comments on the question and assumed there is a backend because of the `proxy_` directives; so **that was my mistake, sorry!**

Comment: np, I was in a hurry anyways, had to post before leaving work so I didn't double check, and when I got home and wrote the test sample I just wrote it from memory not copy/paste, so I missed those mistakes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DCHZyn2J Could you test this on your server? You already have it configured, no clue if its even valid to have another location within a named location, but it might do what you intended to do. PS: Using a non-capturing group in the first location block would make it even faster (`location ~ /(?:foo|bar) {`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68600/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-fleshgrinder).